# Unable to install Zend using composer

Tags: zend-framework, installation, composer-php

I have been using Zend since over 2 years now and have setup environment around 10-12 times but I never got any success installing zend using composer. The error says I should have PHP version same or above required version which is always is the case. I even tried changing the version in the composer to match exactly the version with my PHP and some times installing the exact same version of PHP to match zend requirement and I always gets the same error.

How do I handle this?

Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

zendframework/zendframework 2.3.9 requires php >=5.3.23 -> your PHP version (5.3.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement

PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2011 10:48:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3.6 which you have is older than 5.3.23, because the last number *6* of your version is lower than the last number *23* in the minimum required version of the Zend framework you want to install.

UPDATE YOUR PHP. PHP 5.3 is not maintained anymore. PHP 5.3.6 has serious security bugs that got fixed in later versions, but are still open in your version.

The current PHP version is 5.6. Upgrading from 5.3 to a newer version might have some quirks regarding changed and deprecated features, but face the facts: You will never ever be able to use any recent PHP libraries via Composer because they are all requiring newer PHP versions.